# Why base hover color is not applying

Tags: html, css

I'm facing a problem in `css` of the `<a>` element, This page is using `Bootstrap` `Tab` component. All tabs are connected with their corresponded links. By default `css` of the page has some base styles for `<a>` element i.e.

```
a {
    color: black;
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

On `Tab` there is `ul` element which has some links. I changed the color of links that are in `ul` element. But why `hover` color of the link is not changing to its base `hover` color? I only change the `normal` color not `hover` state color Why this happening?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
          a {
          color: black;
       }

       a:hover {
          color: red;
       }

       .list > li > a {
          color: yellow;
       }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Tab 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-pane active show fade" id="tab1">
        <ul class="list">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Apple</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Banana</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Orange</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Apricot</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane active show fade" id="tab2"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane active show fade" id="tab3"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane active show fade" id="tab4"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the `color: yellow` after you put the `color: red` which mean that CSS will interpret the `color: yellow` more important. so you can put the `color: red` after or add a `!important` (like this `color: red !important`).

Hope this help you!

Comment: Does set color property to `<a>`  means it will also apply on hover state

Comment: If you want to applied it only to the hover state, do that `a:hover {color: red !important;}` but if you remove the `:hover`, it will always applied. The `!important`tag simply say to CSS that whatever is mentioned after, it won't change.

Answer (score 1):

The selector `.list > li > a` has [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) over both `a` and `a:hover` selectors.

You can do the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    a {
      color: black;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: red;
    }
    
    .list > li > a:not(:hover) {
      color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Tab 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-pane active show fade" id="tab1">
    <ul class="list">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Apple</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Banana</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Orange</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Apricot</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane active show fade" id="tab2"></div>
  <div class="tab-pane active show fade" id="tab3"></div>
  <div class="tab-pane active show fade" id="tab4"></div>
</body>

</html>
```